# Java & Google Protocol Buffers: How do I make the jar?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I downloaded the source code (because there is no compiled version), and I compiled it, but it didn't generate a .jar. Instead it made a file that can be executed in a bash/zsh shell.

```
./protoc <params>
```

I need a jar, because this needs jar: 
http://code.google.com/p/protoclipse/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats the compiler.  The details for generating the jar files are [here](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/reference/java-generated.html).

Comment: I could not find any information about jar creation at your link

Comment: From the link...

_When outputting Java code, the protocol buffer compiler's ability to output directly to JAR archives is particularly convenient, as many Java tools are able to read source code directly from JAR files. To output to a JAR file, simply provide an output location **ending in .jar**. Note that only the Java source code is placed in the archive; you must still compile it separately to produce Java class files_

Comment: The generated jar cannot be used

Answer (score 10):

You can download the required jar from [maven central here](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.protobuf/protobuf-java/2.3.0). Click on the link corresponding to **Binary download**

Comment: There's no binary for the latest version ([2.5.0](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.protobuf/protobuf-java/2.5.0/)). I don't know why.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to compile the jar yourself.

To do this you need maven. Download link: http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi

To "install" you just need to unzip the download to a directory and add that directory to your PATH system variable. Please note that the JAVA_HOME system variable should point to JDK installation folder.

Alter you did all this you can go with the command line in the protocol buffers source folder.
the source folder contains a folder called **java** that contains a **README** (with detailed instruction on what you can do). Another important folder is the **src** folder, it must contain the binary "protocol buffers compiler" **protoc.exe** in order to generate the .jar file. So on windows you can download **protoc.exe** from the protobuf download page and copy it in the **src** folder. If you run on linux you will have to compile it yourself.

Once **protoc.exe** is in the **src** folder, you can run '**mvn package**' in the **java** folder. When the command finishes a new folder called target will appear in the java folder. There is the .jar file that you need.

---

For the lazy like me that just want to see the commands:

maven folder: *C:\MyPrograms\apache-maven-3.1.0\*
protoc src folder(contains the source code): *D:\Downloads\protobuf-2.5.0\*
protoc compiler folder (contains protoc.exe): *D:\Downloads\protoc-2.5.0-win32\*
java jdk: *C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21*

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\MyPrograms\apache-maven-3.1.0\bin
SET JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21
cd D:\Downloads\protobuf-2.5.0\
copy D:\Downloads\protoc-2.5.0-win32\protoc.exe src
cd java
mvn package
```

**NOTE:** if you are on linux you will need to replace the copy with a compilation of protoc. also setting the path is most likely not needed or done in a different way.

so instead of:

```
copy D:\Downloads\protoc-2.5.0-win32\protoc.exe src
```

you will have:

```
./configure
make
make check
make install
```

(just make sure the generated binary is copied in the correct folder)

Comment: To build the lite version, use `mvn package -P lite`.